# Google Apps Script - EXPORT all sheets INDIVIDUALLY to PDF

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, export

I've adatped the following script to my demands, but for some reason it always terminates after the 5th or 6th sheet of my spreadsheet, no matter what the content of the sheet actually is...can anyone spot an error or improve the script generally to get it working stable?

This is the error msg I'm receiving:

Fehler
Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 429. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" ... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
savePDFs    @ savePDFs.gs:59

```
function savePDFs( optSSId, optSheetId ) {

  var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
    // Get array of all sheets in spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  // Loop through all sheets, generating PDF files.
  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    
    // If provided a optSheetId, only save it.
    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; 
    
    //export parameters
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
        + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
        // following parameters are optional...
        + '&size=A4'      // paper size
        + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
        + '&scale=4'          // 1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
        + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
        + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
        + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

    var options = {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
      }
    }

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
    
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + ' - ' + sheet.getName() + '.pdf');
    //the pdf is named according to the sheet - this is important for me!

  }
}
```

Comment: By guessing the reason for your current issue, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? My proposed answer is just my guess for your issue. So, if my proposed answer was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script, I'm worried the following situations.

1. Continuous request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`.
2. The hidden sheets might be included in the Spreadsheet.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function savePDFs(optSSId, optSheetId) {
  var ss = (optSSId) ? SpreadsheetApp.openById(optSSId) : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '');
  var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getParents();
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  } else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];

    var isSheetHidden = sheet.isSheetHidden(); // <--- Added
    if (isSheetHidden) continue; // <--- Added

    if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue;
    var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()   //the sheet's Id
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&scale=4'          // 1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false'  //hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    var options = { muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
    var blob = response.getBlob().setName(ss.getName() + ' - ' + sheet.getName() + '.pdf');

    Utilities.sleep(5000); // <--- Added

  }
}
```

- Please adjust `5000` of `Utilities.sleep(5000)` for your actual situation by testing this script.

#### References:

- [isSheetHidden()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isSheetHidden())
- [sleep(milliseconds)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)

Comment: The script does not terminate anymore, it's executed without any error code.
But, unfortunately, it doesn't produce any PDFs....
Could you also explain why you're using the sleep-command here? Thanx!

Comment: @zen or the art of regex Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. And I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw your script, I'm worried following situations. 1. Continuous request using `UrlFetchApp.fetch`. 2. The hidden sheets might be included in the Spreadsheet. About `Could you also explain why you're using the sleep-command here?`, this is for 1st one. About `it doesn't produce any PDFs`, unfortunately, I cannot replicate this. So, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @zen or the art of regex By the way, about `The script does not terminate anymore, it's executed without any error code. But, unfortunately, it doesn't produce any PDFs...`, when I saw your showing script, file is not created. So, I modified just your script. If you want to create the blob as a file, please put `folder.createFile(blob)` just after the line of `var blob = response.getBlob(),,,`. So please be careful about this. If you had already put the script for creating the file, please provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your issue. By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @zen or the art of regex And also, for example, in your script, `if (optSheetId && optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()) continue; ` is used. In this case, if `optSheetId` is a string type like `"0"`, `optSheetId !== sheet.getSheetId()` returns `true`. By this, the script after the if statement is not run. Also, please be careful about this.

Comment: by adding this line of code you suggested 'folder.createFile(blob)' the function works perfectly well - great, thanx!

Comment: @zen or the art of regex Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.